# How can I fix my Python web scraper that returns empty lists when scraping Google search results using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a google search results page with the following objectives:

1. Create a web crawler using python that is able to scrape first 10,000 results for the following
   google search input - site:youtube.com openinapp.co
2. Collect all the given YouTube links of the above search link.
3. Give the results in the JSON/CSV format.

Links should be of YouTube channel instead of scraping youtube video links.

But the scraper is returning empty lists

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

# Function to extract the YouTube channel link from a search result
def extract_channel_link(result):
    link_element = result.find('a')
    link = link_element['href']
    channel_link = link.split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
    return channel_link

# Function to save the results in JSON format
def save_results_json(results):
    with open('youtube_channels.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(results, file, indent=4)

# Main function to perform the web scraping
def scrape_google_search():
    search_query = 'site:youtube.com openinapp.co'
    num_results = 10000
    num_per_page = 10
    base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
    results = []

    for i in range(0, num_results, num_per_page):
        url = base_url + search_query + '&start=' + str(i)
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        search_results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'v7W49e'})

        for result in search_results:
            channel_link = extract_channel_link(result)
            channel_title = result.find('h3').text
            results.append({
                'title': channel_title,
                'channel_link': channel_link
            })

            if len(results) >= num_results:
                break

        if len(results) >= num_results:
            break

    save_results_json(results)

# Run the web crawler
scrape_google_search()
```